# how to compare two files using only one field in the line and outputting the difference and similar

Tags: bash, shell

I am having a problem comparing the output of all the passwd and shadow file and having an output of both the same and difference using only the username field

I am using the grep command

this is my code so far

```
grep -f shadowfile.txt passwordfile.txt > same.txt
grep -Fxvf shadowfile.txt passwordfile.txt > diff.txt
```

I expected the same.txt to have all the users but no entry in the diff one

Comment: Post some sample files with the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

A way I know is to use the [comm](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/comm-invocation.html) command

```
awk -F':' '{ print $1 }' passwordfile.txt | sort > passwordfile.sorted
awk -F':' '{ print $1 }' shadowfile.txt | sort > shadowfile.sorted

comm -12 passwordfile.sorted shadowfile.sorted > same.txt
comm -3 a1 a2 passwordfile.sorted shadowfile.sorted | sed 's/[ \t]*//' > diff.txt
```

The *comm* command require the input data been sorted first
I've used the awk and sort command to generate the *sorted username list* into the temp files

And, for the diff.txt, sed in the pipe is for removing spacing and tab from the output

Answer (score 0):

you can use these commands:

```
awk -F : '{print $1}' passwd.txt shadow.txt |sort | uniq -u > diff.txt
awk -F : '{print $1}' passwd.txt shadow.txt |sort | uniq -d > same.txt
```

Comment: how would I make it so it just searches and uses the username as a parameter?

Comment: at first, it prints users of both files then sort them. The first command `uniq -u` print 
just unique ones and `uniq -d` print just repeated ones.

Comment: and if i want to print out the full path but use the username as a way of verifying both have the same username

Comment: what do you mean of full path?